# OpenGL- move camera inside skybox

Tags: opengl, graphics, camera, skybox

I have a skybox and found out that it is impossible to move inside it ( only rotating, not moving closer to person inside it or so, this is not zoom, it is exactly movement) , as is written in this tutorial https://learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-OpenGL/Cubemaps. As soon as I enable translation for the camera, the skybox become rather ugly, with corners and all sides visible, so the idea to move camera and move the skybox at the same time is not really good. What is the appropriate solution? I think it is a rather obvious problem, but I can not find any solutions anywhere. Or maybe I need to use another construction, not skybox for this purpose.[image]

[image]

here are two states - the first one I get when translate is enabled. I want in the second image to move closer to mountains.

Comment: A lot of things could go wrong here. It will be hard to help without at least seeing a screenshot.

Comment: @jimvonmoon, I have downloaded pictures, bit the code itself is rather large, and it mostly is the same as in tutorial

Comment: Moving around in the skybox, would kind of defeat the overall purpose of a skybox. In relation to the tutorial that is also the intended behavior.

Comment: @Vallentin, then skyboxes are not applied to the tasks when I want to move camera left and right, back and forward? Isn't moving skybox with camera the appropriate solution ( I didn't manage to make it work)?

Comment: I'm unsure what you're saying and what the actual question is. The skybox not moving wouldn't change anything. Because the camera isn't moving either, it's technically the rest of the world that is moving.

Comment: you need to render skybox with its center the same as the camera position ... ignoring any offset movements ... if you are using different position then you can get problems like crossing zfar, nearing edges of skybox etc ...

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question a few years old, the solution to this problem is that you have to set the view matrix **AFTER** you "use" your shader for the the skybox. You can't just set the view matrix once in your loop and expect to work with all shaders that have a view uniform.

So the problem is that OP has something like this based on the tutorial within the main loop:

```
    glm::mat4 view = mCamera.GetViewMatrix(); 

    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);  
    mSkyboxShader.Use();
    mSkyboxShader.SetMat4("view", view);
    mSkyboxShader.SetMat4("projection", projection);
    mSkybox.Render(mSkyboxTexture);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
```

Regardless of code, this treats your skybox like any other object that you can move to. The **solution** is:

```
glm::mat4 view = mCamera.GetViewMatrix(); 

glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);  
mSkyboxShader.Use();
view = mCamera.GetViewMatrix(); <----Solution
mSkyboxShader.SetMat4("view", view);
...
```

You have to update the view after you activate the shader before applying it to a uniform for each shader program that needs a view matrix.

Comment: Can you please explain why you cannot reuse the view matrix? The view matrix should not depend on the shader so unless the OP has changed its value in between calling `GetViewMatrix` and `SetMat4` I see no problem with this.